# Adding an extra button in existing android calling application?

Tags: android, exists

What i want that when a call will come on my android phone then a calling screen will come. I want to update that screen-like if there are to buttons like 1)attend call 2)end call.
I want to add a third button on that screen then how can i do?
or like for dial-bar i want to do some update in that how can i do?

Comment: you have to create a whole new dialler application. to completely replace the one you're currently use.

Answer (score 3):

Can't do that... (unless you are compiling the whole Android framework for your device)